# Можно ли на чистом HTML и CSS сделать несколько блоков одинаковой, но переменной длины внутри родителя?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли **на чистом** HTML и CSS добиться того, чтобы блоки имели одинаковую ширину внутри родителя, но растягивались/сужались по мере растяжения/сужения родительского блока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другими словами, ширина каждого из `n` блоков внутри контейнера без учёта отсупов равна `ParentWidth/n` для любых ширин родителя `Parent Width`.

Если это невозможно на чистом HTML и CSS - так и ответьте и на этом вопрос закроем; JS-решения пока не требуются.

Comment: ты хочешь тег _table_

Comment: display: flex / table - table-cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вариант с `display: table`

+

[table-layout: fixed](http://htmlbook.ru/css/table-layout) - таблица делится на колонки равной ширины. Для корректной работы этого значения обязательно должна быть задана ширина таблицы.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 150px;
}
.b-item{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-item">Другими словами, ширина каждого из n блоков внутри контейнера без учёта отсупов равна ParentWidth/n для любых ширин родителя Parent Width.</div>
  <div class="b-item">Другими словами, ширина каждого из n блоков внутри контейнера без учёта отсупов равна ParentWidth/n для любых ширин родителя Parent Width.Другими словами, ширина каждого из n блоков внутри контейнера без учёта отсупов равна ParentWidth/n для любых ширин родителя Parent Width.</div>
  <div class="b-item">Другими словами, ширина каждого из n блоков внутри контейнера без учёта отсупов равна ParentWidth/n для любых ширин родителя Parent Width. Другими словами, ширина каждого из n блоков внутри контейнера без учёта отсупов равна ParentWidth/n для любых ширин родителя Parent Width. Другими словами, ширина каждого из n блоков внутри контейнера без учёта отсупов равна ParentWidth/n для любых ширин родителя Parent Width.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - задать для внутренних блоков ширину в процентах и расположить колонки в ряд с помощью `float: left`.

Например так:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Так в проблеме `n` блоков а не 3

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, для n ,` .column { width: 100%/n ; }`