# HTML&CSS: разбиение table-контeйнера на строки в резиновой вёрстке

Tags: html, css

Этот вопрос - развитие темы [Можно ли на чистом HTML и CSS сделать несколько блоков одинаковой, но переменной длины внутри родителя?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565348/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-html-%D0%B8-css-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9/565354#565354). В этом моём предыдущем вопросе решением задачи стало использование отображений `table` и `table-cell`.

Теперь задача - с помощью медиазапроса добавить такой диапазон ширин окна, при котором половина блоков уйдёт на вторую строку, но сохранит "резиновые" свойства:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно сделать так: при достижении заданной ширины экрана скрыть половину блоков, а вместо них показать дублированные блоки, которые были скрыты в table-row:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div  class="block">
        <!-- Содержимое-->
    </div>
    <div  class="block">
        <!-- Содержимое-->
    </div>
    <div  class="block"> <!-- это скрываем -->
        <!-- Содержимое-->
    </div>
    <div  class="block"> <!-- это скрываем -->
        <!-- Содержимое-->
    </div>
        <div style="display: table-row"> <!-- это показываем -->
            <div  class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
            </div>

            <div  class="block">
                <!-- Содержимое-->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Недостаток такого метода - необходимость в дублировании блоков. Есть что-нибудь поэлегантнее на чистом HTML и CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать с помощью flexbox. Сделайте пример на весь экран, изменяйте ширину окна и увидите изменения.

`@media (min-width: [значение вашего разрешения, при котором из двух колонок становятся четыре]px)`

В написании css использован метод mobile first, но вы можете это сделать по-другому в зависимости от вашего подхода progressive enhancement или graceful degradation.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: green;
}

.block {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40%;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .block {
    background: purple;
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    Содержимое 1
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    Содержимое 2
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    Содержимое 3
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    Содержимое 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Ссылки:

[Полное руководство по Flexbox (рус.)](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Mobile first (рус.)](http://lpgenerator.ru/blog/2016/03/16/strategiya-mobile-first-chto-eto-i-pochemu-na-nego-stoit-obratit-vnimanie/)

[Graceful Degradation (рус.)](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/izyashchnaya-degradatsiya)

[Progressive Enhancement (рус.)](http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/library/items/graphical_design/progressive-enhancement/)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! А в IE это нормально будет работать? Он вроде как не очень дружит в флексбоксами.

Comment: В IE меньше 10 не будет работать. В IE 10, 11 должно нормально работать, потому что не затрагиваются проблемные места, которые можно посмотреть [здесь вкладка Known issues](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). В IE больше 11 должно работать. К сожалению, у меня нет возможности проверить работу в IE.

Answer (score 1):

Вот до какого решения я додумался сам:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="sub-container>  
        <div class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="sub-container>  
        <div class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
        <div  class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Элементу `.container` ставим `display:table;`.
- Элементу `.sub-container` ставим `inline-table` на том диапазоне, где нужно, чтобы он был в одной строке с другим `.sub-container`, или `table-row`, когда нужно, чтобы он занимал всю строку.
- Элемент `.sub-container` может содержать в себе сколько угодно блоков: как один, так и несколько.