# Кроссбраузерность: выпадание второго блока шириной 50% от родителя

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, кроссбраузерность

Этот вопрос является продолжением темы [HTML&CSS: разбиение table-контeйнера на строки в резиновой вёрстке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565694/htmlcss-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-table-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82e%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5/565697?noredirect=1#comment739934_565697). Была задача на определённых ширинах экрана пловину блоков, изначально находившихся в одной строке, равномерно распределить в 2 строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В целях кроссбраузерности я решил воспользоваться собственным решением:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="sub-container>  
        <div class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="sub-container>  
        <div class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
        <div  class="block">
            <!-- Содержимое-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Элементу `.container` ставим `display:table`;.
- Элементу `.sub-container` ставим `inline-table` на том диапазоне, где нужно, чтобы он был в одной строке с другим `.sub-container`, или `table-row`, когда нужно, чтобы он занимал всю строку.
- Элемент `.sub-container` может содержать в себе сколько угодно блоков: как один, так и несколько.

В Chrome и Safari всё работает хорошо: как Вы можете видеть, каждая `inline-table` занимает 50% от ширины родители (как внешние, так и внутренние отступы равны нулю; внутренние чёрные блоки имеют свои отступы):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отднако в других браузерах, в т. ч. IE и Firefox блоки разваливаются в 2 строки, потому я отнёс эту проблему к категории "кроссбраузерность". Почему так происходит?

---

*Обновление*: Добавил [упрощённый пример](https://jsfiddle.net/4ksx86o0/). На ширинах более 300px в Chrome блоки должны быть в одну строку, но развалиться в две - в IE или Firefox.

Comment: Для начала вопрос: используете ли вы в проекте reset или normalize - возможно в одном из этих браузеров дефолтный стиль подразумевает больший отступ, и проверьте меняется ли ситуация если задать ширину меньше 50%(допустим 49, 48).

Comment: Я не настраивал этих параметров и раньше ими не пользовался... Какой следует попробовать указать?

Comment: Может css добавите?

Comment: Да не вопрос, только он скорее Вас запутает... Можно в виде LESS - правил добавлю, чтобы кода было меньше?

Comment: Здесь LESS не поддерживается. Если хотите помощи добавляйте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu - это не параметры, есть такие "библиотеки" - их суть в том чтобы свести базовые стили браузеров к одному виду. Вот ссылка на reset - http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/, его нужно подключить вверху css файла, попробуйте скажите повлияло ли

Comment: Хорошо, добавил [код](https://jsfiddle.net/4ksx86o0/) на чистом CSS. На ширинах более 300px в Chrome блоки должны быть в одну строку, но развалиться в две - в IE или Firefox.

Comment: Может баг браузеров. Если добавить `.SubContainer` `float: left`, то вроде норм

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы вам не использовать [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), в нем уже решены всем проблемы с кроссбраузерностью

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block-inner">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/dNBYLO